# Loading binaryproto file into caffe library

Tags: c++, caffe

I have a binaryproto file and trying to load into caffe library.
The whole API loading the binary file is as follow.

```
/* Load the mean file in binaryproto format. */
void ExtractFeature::SetMean(const string& mean_file) {
      BlobProto blob_proto;
      ReadProtoFromBinaryFileOrDie(mean_file.c_str(), &blob_proto);

      /* Convert from BlobProto to Blob<float> */
      Blob<float> mean_blob;
      mean_blob.FromProto(blob_proto);
      CHECK_EQ(mean_blob.channels(), num_channels_)
        << "Number of channels of mean file doesn't match input layer.";

      /* The format of the mean file is planar 32-bit float BGR or grayscale. */
      std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
      float* data = mean_blob.mutable_cpu_data();
      for (int i = 0; i < num_channels_; ++i) {
        /* Extract an individual channel. */
        cv::Mat channel(mean_blob.height(), mean_blob.width(), CV_32FC1, data);
        channels.push_back(channel);
        data += mean_blob.height() * mean_blob.width();
      }

      /* Merge the separate channels into a single image. */
      cv::Mat mean;
      cv::merge(channels, mean);

      /* Compute the global mean pixel value and create a mean image
       * filled with this value. */
      cv::Scalar channel_mean = cv::mean(mean);
      mean_ = cv::Mat(input_geometry_, mean.type(), channel_mean);
}
```

I always have error at  `mean_blob.FromProto(blob_proto);`

```
/* Convert from BlobProto to Blob<float> */
      Blob<float> mean_blob;
      mean_blob.FromProto(blob_proto);
```

I provide a correct file path to the function call.

The error is as follow.

```
F0224 14:04:49.170449  5005 blob.cpp:115] Check failed: data_ 
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fb25d11cdcd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fb25d11ed08  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fb25d11c963  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fb25d11f63e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7fb25d6cddb0  caffe::Blob<>::mutable_cpu_data()
    @     0x7fb25d6ce4aa  caffe::Blob<>::FromProto()
    @           0x40848f  ExtractFeature::SetMean()
    @           0x40836a  ExtractFeature::ExtractFeature()
    @           0x40ca7c  main
    @     0x7fb25c865f45  __libc_start_main
    @           0x407f19  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff5a20c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

What could be wrong? There is no such file or directory error, but the file is there and the correct path is provided.

EDIT:
After reading the file at `ReadProtoFromBinaryFileOrDie(mean_file.c_str(), &blob_proto)`, I print the `blob_proto at gdb` and found as

```
(gdb) p blob_proto
$2 = {<google::protobuf::Message> = {<google::protobuf::MessageLite> = {
      _vptr.MessageLite = 0x7ffff6daad50 <vtable for caffe::BlobProto+16>}, <No data fields>}, static kShapeFieldNumber = 7, static kDataFieldNumber = 5, 
  static kDiffFieldNumber = 6, static kDoubleDataFieldNumber = 8, 
  static kDoubleDiffFieldNumber = 9, static kNumFieldNumber = 1, 
  static kChannelsFieldNumber = 2, static kHeightFieldNumber = 3, 
  static kWidthFieldNumber = 4, 
  _internal_metadata_ = {<google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArenaBase<google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet, google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArena>> = {ptr_ = 0x0, static kPtrTagMask = <optimized out>, 
      static kPtrValueMask = <optimized out>}, <No data fields>}, 
  _has_bits_ = {has_bits_ = {28}}, _cached_size_ = 0, data_ = {
    static kInitialSize = <optimized out>, current_size_ = 921600, 
    total_size_ = 1048576, static kRepHeaderSize = 8, rep_ = 0x633a390}, 
  _data_cached_byte_size_ = 4238813, diff_ = {
    static kInitialSize = <optimized out>, current_size_ = 0, total_size_ = 0, 
    static kRepHeaderSize = 8, rep_ = 0x0}, 
  _diff_cached_byte_size_ = 78777232, double_data_ = {
    static kInitialSize = <optimized out>, current_size_ = 0, total_size_ = 0, 
    static kRepHeaderSize = 8, rep_ = 0x0}, 
  _double_data_cached_byte_size_ = 0, double_diff_ = {
    static kInitialSize = <optimized out>, current_size_ = 0, total_size_ = 0, 
    static kRepHeaderSize = 8, rep_ = 0x0}, 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
  _double_diff_cached_byte_size_ = -9848, shape_ = 0x0, num_ = 0, 
  channels_ = 480, height_ = 640, width_ = 3}
```

That means image format at `blob_proto` is wrong (actual image has channel 3, width 640 and height 480).

That could be because of two reasons
(1)Saving the mean.binaryproto file has wrong format.
My program for saving mean.binaryproto file is

```
def create_protobinary(avg_img):
    #avg_img is your numpy array with the average data 
    blob = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.BlobProto();
    blob.channels, blob.height, blob.width = avg_img.shape;
    blob.data.extend(avg_img.astype(float).flat);
    binaryproto_file = open('mean.binaryproto', 'wb' );
    binaryproto_file.write(blob.SerializeToString());
    binaryproto_file.close();
```

(2)Or `ReadProtoFromBinaryFileOrDie(mean_file.c_str(), &blob_proto);`
Reading the file into blob_proto has problem.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I found the error at blob.channels, blob.height, blob.width = avg_img.shape;.It should be blob.height, blob.width ,blob.channels = avg_img.shape;